# Problem with @SerializedName by parsing JSON in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, android-room

I have problem with serializing the variable name which comes from backend,
from backend come JSON with string variable "n".

```
@SerializedName("n")
val name: String
```

it can't serialized it, the object return null to name variable.
But if I choose with no serialization

```
val n: String
```

it works fine.

My gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```